# Sylius 1.12. theme assets loading problem

Tags: sylius

I am new to Sylius, just learning and going through docs. I added new theme in 'themes' directory - MyTheme. Inside, i have 'assets' and 'templates' directories. Templates are working, but logo I added inside `'themes/MyTheme/assets/shop/images/logo-email-big.png'` is not working when I call it inside template like that:

`<img src="{{ asset('build/app/shop/images/logo-email-big.png', 'app.shop') }}" alt="Logo" class="ui small image" />`

I also added it into 'themes -> MyTheme -> assets -> shop -> entry.js' this:   `import './images/logo-email-big.png';`
I did clear the cache and ran `php bin/console sylius:theme:assets:install`, but still - there is no image in there.

Am I doing it the correct way?
Where should theme assets be located?

I tried also yarn build, but no changes.

Comment: I would like to do something similar and I am facing the same issue.